# Troubleshoot High CPU Usage on Windows Server

Tags: java, performance, cpu

We have J2EE based web application.  Intermittently we are facing high CPU usage (80-90%) on our production environment.
We are unable to replicate it on our QA environment.

Production Environment: Windows 2012 Server (64 bit), JDK 1.8 (64 bit)

For troubleshooting we have taken thread dump.
It shows total 215 threads.

```
111 threads are in WAITING status
34 threads are in RUNNABLE status
67 threads are in TIMED_WAITING status
3 threads are in BLOCKED status
```

How can we find which threads are causing high CPU usage?

## Thread Dump

> 2016-03-01 11:07:52 Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
> (25.5-b02 mixed mode):
>
> "Thread-739969" - Thread t@807668    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <229fc226> (a org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread.run(ConcurrentLRUCache.java:604)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - None
>
> "Thread-739968" - Thread t@807667    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <5a578345> (a org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread.run(ConcurrentLRUCache.java:604)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - None
>
> "Thread-739963" - Thread t@807662    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <20851ef7> (a org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread.run(ConcurrentLRUCache.java:604)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - None
>
> "Thread-739962" - Thread t@807661    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <35061b89> (a org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread.run(ConcurrentLRUCache.java:604)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - None
>
> "Thread-739960" - Thread t@807659    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <3491a931> (a org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread.run(ConcurrentLRUCache.java:604)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - None
>
> "Thread-739959" - Thread t@807658    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <6395c27d> (a org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread)   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.ConcurrentLRUCache$CleanupThread.run(ConcurrentLRUCache.java:604)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - None
>
> "httpShardExecutor-3-thread-57429-processing-{core=actionscomments,
> replica=core_node1,
> ShardRequest.shards=s1.example.com:8983//solr//actionscomments|s1r1.example.com:8983//solr//actionscomments,
> node_name=10.120.112.31:8983_solr, shard=shard1,
> collection=actionscomments,
> ShardRequest.urlList=[http:////s1r1.example.com:8983//solr//actionscomments,
> http:////s1.example.com:8983//solr//actionscomments]}" - Thread t@807648
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE  at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
> org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.isDataAvailable(SocketInputBuffer.java:95)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.isStale(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:310)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.isStale(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:158)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:433)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
> at
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:466)
> at
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:235)
> at
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:227)
> at
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.doRequest(LBHttpSolrClient.java:376)
> at
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.request(LBHttpSolrClient.java:328)
> at
> org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory.makeLoadBalancedRequest(HttpShardHandlerFactory.java:246)
> at
> org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:183)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:148)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>
> - locked  (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Answer (score 2):

Use [visualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/) to identify the thread consuming the CPU. A good article about interpreting the thread dump can be found on DZone: [how-analyze-java-thread-dumps](https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps).

This should be allow you to identify the thread and maybe you can already direct identify the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) (TopThread plugin) or [visulavm](https://visualvm.java.net/) (HotThread Detector plugin), these have plugins to explain what you are looking for. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930915/which-java-thread-is-hogging-the-cpu) question also.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is a powerful tool in debug windows performance issue. It can check deadlock thread or memory issue.