# Spring Boot Admin high cpu usage / details page refresh interval

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am in the 'forbidden' scenario of having SBA server and client in one app (so there is only one app registered for any SBA server instance, which is itself). For various reasons I can't change that.

I see a huge cpu usage when being on the insights>details page. No clue why, the only thing I can think of is I have a "lot of" caches (like 40). Any guesses on that cpu usage?

The second thing is: I am unable to find a config setting how often the graphs on the detail page get updated. Is there no way to get that "slower" ? To try out if that may be the reason.

Comment: could be better to ask this question in other communities than here.-

Comment: Does this help: [Which Java thread is hogging the CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930915/which-java-thread-is-hogging-the-cpu)

Answer (score 1):

My hints to less the performance hunger of Spring Boot Admin is to reduce the checking interval of the services. You can do this in your Spring Boot Admin properties/yml file via the following in yml for example to refresh status of connected services every 2 minutes:

```
spring:
       boot:
        admin:
          monitor:
            status-interval: 120000ms
            status-lifetime: 120000ms
            info-interval: 120000ms
            info-lifetime: 120000ms
```

Further details for configuration the monitor interval can be found here: http://docs.spring-boot-admin.com/current/server.html

I am not aware how to configure the refresh interval of the graphics such as Threads, Memory, etc. and I think there is no configuration possible for that, currently.

I hope that this information helps you.