# Spring boot admin – high CPU usage on client

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have one application which uses Spring Boot Admin Server library (v2.2.1) to monitor the other applications with integrated Spring Boot Client library (v2.2.1). It works very well; server tracks status of client applications with low performance impact.

Nevertheless, when I open page *Insight -> Details* (default page), CPU usage of client application grows to 90 – 100 % which causes that my application (running on 1CPU system) responds very slowly. Other pages of Spring Boot Server are OK.

According to my observation, high CPU usage is caused by frequent refresh (1 second) of information there, especially charts. In my case sends Spring Boot Admin about 16 requests in 1 second. Processing each takes about 400 ms (last number)

```
2020-03-11 08:31:45.290 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:ui-logbook,result:miss" 200 HTTP/1.0 308 421
2020-03-11 08:31:45.291 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:area-services,result:miss" 200 HTTP/1.0 312 438
2020-03-11 08:31:45.291 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:area-services,result:hit" 200 HTTP/1.0 286 437
2020-03-11 08:31:45.290 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/cache.size?tag=name:area-services" 200 HTTP/1.0 314 420
2020-03-11 08:31:45.292 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:ui-logbook,result:hit" 200 HTTP/1.0 282 428
2020-03-11 08:31:45.426 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/cache.size?tag=name:ui-logbook" 200 HTTP/1.0 310 100
2020-03-11 08:31:46.513 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.threads.peak" 200 HTTP/1.0 219 436
2020-03-11 08:31:46.520 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.threads.live" 200 HTTP/1.0 215 434
2020-03-11 08:31:46.520 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/process.cpu.usage" 200 HTTP/1.0 207 434
2020-03-11 08:31:46.520 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/system.cpu.usage" 200 HTTP/1.0 177 433
2020-03-11 08:31:46.521 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.gc.pause" 200 HTTP/1.0 401 433
2020-03-11 08:31:46.945 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.threads.daemon" 200 HTTP/1.0 179 398
2020-03-11 08:31:46.991 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max?tag=area:heap" 200 HTTP/1.0 282 425
2020-03-11 08:31:46.998 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max?tag=area:nonheap" 200 HTTP/1.0 369 420
2020-03-11 08:31:46.998 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.used?tag=area:nonheap" 200 HTTP/1.0 318 422
2020-03-11 08:31:46.999 127.0.0.1 - GET "/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.used?tag=area:heap" 200 HTTP/1.0 233 420
```

Is there any way how to reduce refresh rate in order to reduce CPU load on client system?

So far I have found only [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868589/2750004) but suggested solution did not work.

Thanks for sharing ideas.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the exact same issue