# Spring Boot application starts using all CPU

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a basic Spring Boot (1.3.2.RELEASE) application. I run this application from IntelliJ IDEA as a standalone application (`SpringApplication.run(...)`).

I have noticed multiple times that after leaving the application running for a while, the java process starts using all available CPU. I have verified that it is in fact the Spring process, and not for example IDEA. This occurs on my development machine, while I am not doing any kind of interaction with it.

Using `jstack` I took 3 different stacktraces with a minute in between. The threads that are different between these stacktraces are listed here:

Diff log1 and log2

```
#log 1
"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002168f800 nid=0x17fc runnable [0x0000000019a9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.resetWakeupSocket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.resetWakeupSocket(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:473)
    - locked <0x00000000830da710> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:174)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830d3130> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830d3120> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830d2fd0> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:342)

#log2
"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002168f800 nid=0x17fc runnable [0x0000000019a9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830d3130> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830d3120> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830d2fd0> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:342)
```

Diff log2 and log3:

```
#log2
"http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-1" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ab7d000 nid=0x2a00 runnable [0x000000002509e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3628> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3618> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3398> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


#log3
"http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-1" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ab7d000 nid=0x2a00 runnable [0x000000002509e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.resetWakeupSocket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.resetWakeupSocket(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:473)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3c00> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:174)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3628> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3618> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3398> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For reference, here is the full stacktrace of log1:

```
2016-03-24 15:45:34
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode):

"http-nio-8080-exec-10" #38 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000023a3f800 nid=0x2a14 waiting on condition [0x000000001984e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-9" #37 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021716000 nid=0x2974 waiting on condition [0x00000000277df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-8" #35 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021715000 nid=0x12e0 waiting on condition [0x00000000276bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-7" #34 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021714800 nid=0x904 waiting on condition [0x00000000271be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-6" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021713800 nid=0x29a4 waiting on condition [0x000000001fdfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-5" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021712000 nid=0x12c4 waiting on condition [0x00000000267ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-4" #29 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021711800 nid=0x1098 waiting on condition [0x000000002047f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-3" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021710800 nid=0x1c38 waiting on condition [0x000000001bbde000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-exec-2" #27 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021710000 nid=0x1dd0 waiting on condition [0x0000000022a2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"DestroyJavaVM" #26 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002170f000 nid=0x28cc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"http-nio-8080-exec-1" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ab7e800 nid=0x29f8 waiting on condition [0x0000000026d4e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000830901c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0" #23 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ab7d800 nid=0x2a60 runnable [0x0000000026c2e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    - locked <0x00000000830c2f98> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:682)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-1" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ab7d000 nid=0x2a00 runnable [0x000000002509e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3628> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3618> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830c3398> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-0" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ab7c000 nid=0x18b8 runnable [0x000000001891f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830c43a0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830c4390> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830c4110> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002168f800 nid=0x17fc runnable [0x0000000019a9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.resetWakeupSocket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.resetWakeupSocket(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:473)
    - locked <0x00000000830da710> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:174)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000830d3130> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000830d3120> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000830d2fd0> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:342)

"Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[349885916:1458815021571]" #19 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001cc52800 nid=0x80c in Object.wait() [0x000000002258e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000000820f5608> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"container-0" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b2e9000 nid=0x2b44 waiting on condition [0x00000000226bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:407)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer$1.run(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:140)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018de5800 nid=0x2294 waiting on condition [0x000000002037f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1344)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018aca000 nid=0xac4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018a61800 nid=0x2704 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018a53000 nid=0x2838 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018a4e000 nid=0x2bbc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Event Helper Thread" #7 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018a3b800 nid=0x444 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018a2a000 nid=0x2514 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018a29000 nid=0x201c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x00000000174eb000 nid=0x1534 in Object.wait() [0x0000000018a1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000081f3ddf0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000174e9800 nid=0x2700 in Object.wait() [0x000000001881f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x0000000081fa4788> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000174e4000 nid=0x1070 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002155000 nid=0x141c runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002156800 nid=0x2b9c runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002158000 nid=0x1c18 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002159800 nid=0x1fa0 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018aca800 nid=0x1d74 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 16054
```

The only related source that I could find was an old bug report: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45661

Any advice on how to solve or track this bug down?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755899/monitor-cpu-usage-per-thread-in-java) may be of use

Comment: I have a very similar problem with Tomcat 8.0. I am running Tomcat 8.0.33 using Java 1.8.0_77 on a Windows 2008 R2 that is deployed in a VMWare ESXi 5.1 server. Is you environment similar? Did you find any workaround?

Comment: My environment is simpler: a win7x64 enterprise. This is about my own development machine. I haven't found a workaround yet, but one related link is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153821 (an issue in IntelliJ IDEA that prevents me from actually debugging the problem).

Comment: Issue also discussed under [Tomcat 8 uses high CPU](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201604.mbox/thread) without any resolution from developers

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing protocols in Tomcat connectors to force using NIO.2 instead of NIO.

Modify server.xml this way:

```
<Connector port="8080"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8009" 
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol" 
  redirectPort="8443" />
```

It seems that there is some Java bug when using NIO in this context.